# Tkinter combobox loop again. Getting the results

Tags: list, loops, dictionary, tkinter, combobox

I created a group of comboboxes from looping a list and
used dict key as item em combolist. Problems: I cannot get back results to a 'results' list. All comboboxes change at same time. I´ve studied other posts about the subject, but I cant understand the concept involved in the solution.
To sum: The code generate 3 combobox but they change togeter, and I cant append results.

Thanks for your help, in advance:

#-----------------------code

```
from tkinter import 
from tkinter import ttk
win = Tk()
win.geometry('400x600')
win.title('combobox')


result =[] #--> the new list with results of comboboxes

opts = StringVar()

anyFruits =['any_grape', 'any_tomato', 'any_banana'] 
#--> list just to generate the loop 


fruits = {'specialgrape':'specialgrape', 'specialtomato':'specialtomato','specialbanana':'specialbanana'}
#--> dictonary to generate drop down options menu (key of dict)

for index, fruit in enumerate(anyFruits):

    mycombo = ttk.Combobox(win, 
                           values= (list(fruits.keys())),textvariable=opts)

    mycombo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda event, index=index: fruit_callBack(index, event))
    
    mycombo.pack()


    
def fruit_callBack(index, event):
    
    for opts in mycombo:
        
        result.append(opts)



def print_():        
    print(result)


bt = Button(win,command= print_)

bt.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: First problem solved: to individually fill in comboboxes opts must be placed inside loop

Comment: What do you expect to happen. They change at same time because they all have same `textvariable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value all change together because all `Combobox` have same `textvariable`. Hence change in one, will force the others to keep the value same. Anyway, you are appending it wrong too, you do not need to pass in `index`, just pass the combobox itself and append the value inside it:

```py
for index, fruit in enumerate(anyFruits):
    mycombo = ttk.Combobox(win,values=list(fruits.keys()))
    mycombo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',lambda e,cmb=mycombo: fruit_callBack(e,cmb))   
    mycombo.pack()
   
def fruit_callBack(event,cmb):
    result.append(cmb.get())
```

Comment: Thank you,  for the enlightenment.

Comment: Hei! You really solved the problem. Thanks a lot. Have a nice weekend.

Comment: Nice weekend to you too